# usb_cam and image_view keeps giving "videre INI" error

Tags: usb-cam, image-view, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using usb_cam and image_view packages to capture images from a usb camera. However, after I launch the nodes, the image_saver node in image_view package keeps giving me the same errors:

```
Videre INI format can only save calibrations using the plumb distortion model. Use the YAML format instead.
```

I did some research, and guess that it is complaining that I did not supply a calibration yaml file when launching the node.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241763/usb_cam-and-image_view-keeps-giving-%22videre-ini%22-error/) by [rosjade](https://answers.ros.org/users/27755/rosjade/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just a try out, can you check the package.xml in camera_calibration_parsers? Is the build and run dependent are "yaml-cpp". if not, try changing it to "yaml-cpp" as follows It might help.
(I am using ros-kinetic)

`<build_depend>yaml-cpp</build_depend>`

`<run_depend>yaml-cpp</run_depend>`

For Navigating to "camera_calibration_parsers" type the following command:

rospack camera_calibration_parsers

---

Originally posted by [ghkraju](https://answers.ros.org/users/27712/ghkraju/) with karma: 80 on 2016-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0